# Opening and closing stock in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I need a report of Opening and closing balance of the stock. So for that from the Inventory where will I get the value ? If anybody knows can you please comment or answer here ? I'm looking for Odoo 11.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a functional question and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stock Valuation report for this. This menu is located under `Inventory>Report>Inventory Valuation`. You can select date and compute stock valuation till that date, so inventory until previous date can be your opening and current inventory be your closing value.